# How to insert/dump all keyboard macros at once?

Tags: evil, keyboard-macros

Is there a way to show all keyboard macros [(similar to `insert-kbd-macro`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22820324/432509) without having to first name each macro?

---

*Using macros with evil-mode in case this makes a difference.*

Comment: How can you have multiple macros without naming them first?

Comment: Using evil-mode's Q-key, then an Alpha Key. (Maybe this names them too?). Either way - how to dump all of them at once?

Comment: @Turn Emacs has a macro ring.

Answer (score 1):

Evil-specific answer:

In Vim, macros are saved in registers, so `:reg[isters]` displays them as well.

Comment: Is there a way to show these in a format I can run as elisp code? - as with `insert-kbd-macro`

Comment: Keyboard macros are saved as a string of characters that have been recorded in some particular Emacs state. Conversion to elisp will be lossy because the information about the Emacs states is lost. Just execute the keyboard macro, like by binding the string to a key or programmatically with `execute-kbd-macro`.

Comment: So how can I get all these strings of characters? - `insert-kbd-macro` seems to be able to show them.

Comment: They live in `(evil-register-list)`.